# How to sort a list of alphanumerics with complicated strings

Tags: python, list

I need your help because Im stuck at this problem.
I want to sort a list which consist of ugly string combined with integers. The ordering that i desire is the following: Starting with

```
f(-2,-2)=..., 
f(-2,-1)=..., 
f(-2,0)=...,
f(-2,1)=...,
f(-2,2)=..., 
..., 
f(2,2)= ...
```

I've tried to use the in-built function sorted but didn't help. Can somebody help out a beginner.

```
list1 = ['f(-2,-2) = 0', 'f(-2,-1) = 0', 'f(-2,0) = 0', 'f(-1,-2) = 0', 'f(-1,-1) = 0', 'f(-1,0) = 0', 'f(0,-2) = 0', 'f(0,-1) = 0', 'f(-2,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))', 'f(-2,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d+2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d-2)*m4^4)*den(2*m10^2))', 'f(-1,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(p11+m10^2-m4^2)', 'f(-1,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11+(d)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den(2*m10^2))', 'f(0,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(1)', 'f(0,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*((d-2)*den(2*m10^2))', 'f(1,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d)*p11^2+((-2*d)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))', 'f(1,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(p11-m10^2+m4^2)', 'f(1,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(1)', 'f(1,1) = scalar2_qp_1216(1,1)*(1)', 'f(1,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(p11^2+(-2*m10^2-2*m4^2)*p11+m10^4+(-2*m4^2)*m10^2+m4^4))', 'f(2,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d+2)*m4^4)*den(2*m4^2))', 'f(2,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^2)*den(2*m4^2))', 'f(2,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(2*m4^2))', 'f(2,1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^2+((-4*m4^2)*m10^2-4*m4^4)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^4+(-4*m4^4)*m10^2+2*m4^6))', 'f(2,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*m10^2+(2*d^2-13*d+18)*m4^4)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^4+((-8*m4^2)*m10^2-8*m4^4)*p11^3+((12*m4^2)*m10^4+(8*m4^4)*m10^2+12*m4^6)*p11^2+((-8*m4^2)*m10^6+(8*m4^4)*m10^4+(8*m4^6)*m10^2-8*m4^8)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^8+(-8*m4^4)*m10^6+(12*m4^6)*m10^4+(-8*m4^8)*m10^2+2*m4^10))', 'f(0,0) = 0']
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the [built-in `sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) but if you don't want a literal (character-based) order, you will have to specify it.

Comment: Yes, thank you all for the answers. Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

We can use a combination of [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and a [custom sort key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) to achieve the desired result.

```
import ast
import re

pattern = re.compile('\([+-]?[0-9]*,[+-]?[0-9]*\)')

def custom_sort(item):
    match = pattern.search(item).group(0)
    x, y = ast.literal_eval(match)
    return x, y

sorted(list1, key=custom_sort)

['f(-2,-2) = 0',
 'f(-2,-1) = 0',
 'f(-2,0) = 0',
 'f(-2,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))',
 'f(-2,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d+2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d-2)*m4^4)*den(2*m10^2))',
 'f(-1,-2) = 0',
 'f(-1,-1) = 0',
 'f(-1,0) = 0',
 'f(-1,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(p11+m10^2-m4^2)',
 'f(-1,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11+(d)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den(2*m10^2))',
 'f(0,-2) = 0',
 'f(0,-1) = 0',
 'f(0,0) = 0',
 'f(0,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(1)',
 'f(0,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*((d-2)*den(2*m10^2))',
 'f(1,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d)*p11^2+((-2*d)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))',
 'f(1,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(p11-m10^2+m4^2)',
 'f(1,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(1)',
 'f(1,1) = scalar2_qp_1216(1,1)*(1)',
 'f(1,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(p11^2+(-2*m10^2-2*m4^2)*p11+m10^4+(-2*m4^2)*m10^2+m4^4))',
 'f(2,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d+2)*m4^4)*den(2*m4^2))',
 'f(2,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^2)*den(2*m4^2))',
 'f(2,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(2*m4^2))',
 'f(2,1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^2+((-4*m4^2)*m10^2-4*m4^4)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^4+(-4*m4^4)*m10^2+2*m4^6))',
 'f(2,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*m10^2+(2*d^2-13*d+18)*m4^4)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^4+((-8*m4^2)*m10^2-8*m4^4)*p11^3+((12*m4^2)*m10^4+(8*m4^4)*m10^2+12*m4^6)*p11^2+((-8*m4^2)*m10^6+(8*m4^4)*m10^4+(8*m4^6)*m10^2-8*m4^8)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^8+(-8*m4^4)*m10^6+(12*m4^6)*m10^4+(-8*m4^8)*m10^2+2*m4^10))']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) Python module to sort this list according to the natural ordering of those signed numbers.

You can install it using:

```
$ pip install natsort
```

(Though the exact details may vary on whether you're using a virtualenv, venv, pipenv, etc. Or whether you're on a platform where you need extra permissions to install modules platform-wise, in which case you might consider installing it inside your home directory. Search the web, or StackOverflow, you're surely to find posts on how to install Python modules for your setup.)

Once installed, you can import it with:

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns
```

And then you can sort your list using:

```
natsorted(list1, alg=ns.SIGNED)
```

Which produces:

```
['f(-2,-2) = 0',
 'f(-2,-1) = 0',
 'f(-2,0) = 0',
 'f(-2,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))',
 'f(-2,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d+2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d-2)*m4^4)*den(2*m10^2))',
 'f(-1,-2) = 0',
 'f(-1,-1) = 0',
 'f(-1,0) = 0',
 'f(-1,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(p11+m10^2-m4^2)',
 'f(-1,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11+(d)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den(2*m10^2))',
 'f(0,-2) = 0',
 'f(0,-1) = 0',
 'f(0,0) = 0',
 'f(0,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(1)',
 'f(0,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*((d-2)*den(2*m10^2))',
 'f(1,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d)*p11^2+((-2*d)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))',
 'f(1,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(p11-m10^2+m4^2)',
 'f(1,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(1)',
 'f(1,1) = scalar2_qp_1216(1,1)*(1)',
 'f(1,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(p11^2+(-2*m10^2-2*m4^2)*p11+m10^4+(-2*m4^2)*m10^2+m4^4))',
 'f(2,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d+2)*m4^4)*den(2*m4^2))',
 'f(2,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^2)*den(2*m4^2))',
 'f(2,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(2*m4^2))',
 'f(2,1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^2+((-4*m4^2)*m10^2-4*m4^4)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^4+(-4*m4^4)*m10^2+2*m4^6))',
 'f(2,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*m10^2+(2*d^2-13*d+18)*m4^4)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^4+((-8*m4^2)*m10^2-8*m4^4)*p11^3+((12*m4^2)*m10^4+(8*m4^4)*m10^2+12*m4^6)*p11^2+((-8*m4^2)*m10^6+(8*m4^4)*m10^4+(8*m4^6)*m10^2-8*m4^8)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^8+(-8*m4^4)*m10^6+(12*m4^6)*m10^4+(-8*m4^8)*m10^2+2*m4^10))']
```

You can easily the sort order matches your stated expectation.

Comment: Awesome. Thank alot.

Answer (score 1):

First find a way to get the data to sort on out of each list item:

```py
import re
list1 = ['f(-2,-2) = 0', 'f(-2,-1) = 0', 'f(-2,0) = 0', 'f(-1,-2) = 0', 'f(-1,-1) = 0', 'f(-1,0) = 0', 'f(0,-2) = 0', 'f(0,-1) = 0', 'f(-2,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))', 'f(-2,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d+2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d-2)*m4^4)*den(2*m10^2))', 'f(-1,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(p11+m10^2-m4^2)', 'f(-1,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(((d-2)*p11+(d)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den(2*m10^2))', 'f(0,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*(1)', 'f(0,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*((d-2)*den(2*m10^2))', 'f(1,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d)*p11^2+((-2*d)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^4)*den(d))', 'f(1,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(p11-m10^2+m4^2)', 'f(1,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(1)', 'f(1,1) = scalar2_qp_1216(1,1)*(1)', 'f(1,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(p11^2+(-2*m10^2-2*m4^2)*p11+m10^4+(-2*m4^2)*m10^2+m4^4))', 'f(2,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(2*d+4)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d)*m4^2)*m10^2+(d+2)*m4^4)*den(2*m4^2))', 'f(2,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(d)*m4^2)*den(2*m4^2))', 'f(2,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*((d-2)*den(2*m4^2))', 'f(2,1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11+(-d+2)*m10^2+(-d+2)*m4^2)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^2+((-4*m4^2)*m10^2-4*m4^4)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^4+(-4*m4^4)*m10^2+2*m4^6))', 'f(2,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(((d-2)*p11^2+((-2*d+4)*m10^2+(-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*p11+(d-2)*m10^4+((-2*d^2+12*d-16)*m4^2)*m10^2+(2*d^2-13*d+18)*m4^4)*den((2*m4^2)*p11^4+((-8*m4^2)*m10^2-8*m4^4)*p11^3+((12*m4^2)*m10^4+(8*m4^4)*m10^2+12*m4^6)*p11^2+((-8*m4^2)*m10^6+(8*m4^4)*m10^4+(8*m4^6)*m10^2-8*m4^8)*p11+(2*m4^2)*m10^8+(-8*m4^4)*m10^6+(12*m4^6)*m10^4+(-8*m4^8)*m10^2+2*m4^10))', 'f(0,0) = 0']

for item in list1:
    print ([(i[0],i[1]) for i in re.findall(r'^f\((-?\d+),(-?\d+)\)', item)])
```

This prints out a nice list of number pairs, so that `findall` works. The `findall` expression is fairly straightforward, as regular expressions go, because all it does is find a sequence `f(number₁,number₂)` in each list item and returns a tuple `(number₁,number₂)`. That is the data to sort on.

With that, you can use the tuple as input for the `key` argument in [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```py
for i in sorted(list1, key=lambda item: [(int(i[0]),int(i[1])) for i in [(i[0],i[1]) for i in re.findall(r'f\((-?\d+),(-?\d+)\)', item)]]):
    print (i)
```

with the result:

```
f(-2,-2) = 0
f(-2,-1) = 0
f(-2,0) = 0
f(-2,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)...
f(-2,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)...
f(-1,-2) = 0
f(-1,-1) = 0
f(-1,0) = 0
f(-1,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)...
f(-1,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)...
f(0,-2) = 0
f(0,-1) = 0
f(0,0) = 0
f(0,1) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*...
f(0,2) = scalar2_qp_1211(0,1)*...
f(1,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*...
f(1,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*...
f(1,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(...
f(1,1) = scalar2_qp_1216(1,1)*...
f(1,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(...
f(2,-2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*...
f(2,-1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*...
f(2,0) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(...
f(2,1) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(...
f(2,2) = scalar2_qp_016(1,0)*(...
```

Comment: imo it would be more readable if the custom sort key was made into a function, for a beginner the `lambda` expression might be hard to digest, just my 2 cents. otherwise nicely done, looks like we had the same idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the built-in `sort`, I think it should be possible to split your string into tuples according to the sorting logic you want to apply.

Here is a generic example:

```py
a = [("c", 2), ("a", 2), ("a", 1), ("b", 4)]
print(sorted(a))
```

This prints:

```py
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 2)]
```

In your case, you could split `"f(-2,1)"` up into `["f(", -2, ",", 1, ")"]`, and so on, depending on how complicated your entries are.